# How To Display a Popup Containing an Image in Excel Userform When Mouse is Hovering on It

Tags: excel, userform, vba

**Consider the following:**

I have an excel userform that contains image objects that have been reduced in size.
When the user hovers on an image, I would like the image to popup and display the same image but in its original size.

An example of how it would work is by adding text to `ControlTipText` and when the cursor is hovering the image, it would display the text, but instead of text, I would like it to display the image.

**How it would look like**

The userform:
[image: The userform]

When cursor hovers on the image:
[image: When cursor hovers on the image]

**I've tried the following:**

Using the `MouseMove` function, when cursor is on the image, it would display another userform of the enlarged version of that image.

I've also tried using a timer to close the userform after a few seconds.

Both methods are not user-friendly as the user would have to close the userform themselves or wait for the userform to close automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could resize the main UserForm on mouse-over of a thumbnail so that it reveals a larger image. Start with a user form laid out like this:

[image: user form]

*Before use, resize the UserForm so that it hides the large image.*

The thumbnails fit within `width = 100`, whilst the full form is `width = 340`.

Add subs like the following to the UserForm:

```
Private Sub Image1_MouseMove(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)
    UpdateLargeImage UserForm1.Image1.Picture
End Sub
Private Sub Image2_MouseMove(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)
    UpdateLargeImage UserForm1.Image2.Picture
End Sub
Private Sub UpdateLargeImage(ByVal Image As Object)
    UserForm1.Width = 340
    UserForm1.Image3.Picture = Image
End Sub
Private Sub UserForm_MouseMove(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)
    UserForm1.Width = 100
End Sub
```

You can see the two resizing commands depending what the mouse is moving over, and also that there is a generic sub `UpdateLargeImage` which reveals the larger image and sets it to whatever image was in the thumbnail.

---

Test:

[image: test]

Comment: Hmm, I never thought of this workaround. Thanks for your help and detailed answer!

Comment: No worries, glad I could help :)