# Is there a way use the mouseover function on an active label to have a gif popup?

Tags: excel, vba, image, mouseover

As the title states, I want to have a shape with text in it (think of a flowchart), then make an active label over it. So when one moves their mouse over the label, a GIF will pop up. Then when they move the mouse off of the label, it will disappear.

The closest thing I have so far is this (but it could be entirely wrong):

```
Private Sub Label1_MouseMove(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As 
Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)


Sheet1.Shapes("situation.GIF").Visible = True


End Sub
```

Any advice or help would be amazing, if you have any questions please don't hesitate to ask!

Regards

Comment: there is no event for shapes unless you write yourself which would not be that easy, I had the same problem so I went with comments. You can insert a picture in a comment so when the mouse is over the cell (label etc) it will pop the picture

Comment: Right, so if you use an active control, you can create a label to put on top of a shape. Then you remove the caption and make that label transparent so it's there but you can't see it. You can then add a macro with a MouseMove event that triggers when you move your mouse over it. Do you (or anyone else) know how to make a picture pop-up when you move over that label?

Comment: see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45073072/how-to-display-a-popup-containing-an-image-in-excel-userform-when-mouse-is-hover